# Classification of river

Tags: rivers

I would like to know how can we determine if the river is wide. Is there any classification or consideration that can be done based on the width, depth, and length of the river?

Comment: which part of the river? the classification of rivers applies to section of river not the entire thing.

Comment: Also 'wide' is often applied subjectively based on local context. E.g. in the UK the River Thames is often described as wide, at least in its lower reaches, but if it was transplanted to the Amazon it would hardly be thought of as a small stream!

Comment: Please Accept the given answer If you are satisfied with it. If you are Not write a smal commend and I try to give an additional answer :) all the best

Answer (score 10):

It is not easy to classify rivers, especially on the basis that many rivers evolve (see fig) and that man often interferes with the river, but there is a good classification according to Dong-Geun Yoo, which gives different criteria for river classification. For example, the shape of the erosion valley, the width of the river branches, etc.

[image]

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/River-classification-delineation-showing-longitudinal-cross-sectional-and-plan-views-of_fig3_315965422  (also more details)

Comment: What a great graphic/data, I certainly learned something!